# MVVM Light Locator: Register all derivates of ViewModelBase

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

This is my locator. For demonstration purposes, I stripped all ViewModels except two. Since I basically need to register all `: ViewModelBase` objects, I was thinking of using **reflection** to do this. The properties of the class itself can't be "created" like this, but the registration can. However, I'm struggling with reflection on generic methods here.

```
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Ioc;
using Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation;
using System;

namespace DevExplorer
{
    public class ViewModelLocator
    {
        public WindowMainViewModel WindowMain => SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<WindowMainViewModel>();
        public WindowAboutViewModel WindowAbout => ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<WindowAboutViewModel>(GetKey());

        public ViewModelLocator()
        {
            ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);

            //REFACTOR: Get by reflection
            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<WindowMainViewModel>();
            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<WindowAboutViewModel>();
        }

        private string GetKey()
        {
            return Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like usually, formulating a proper question required me dig in deeper, so after some time I came up with this code for the `ViewModelLocator` constructor. And I would like to share it, since I feel this is an at least *somewhat* common MVVM Light problem that I haven't found any solution to, yet.

- First, all types of `ViewModelBase` are retrieved from all assemblies.
- Then, we need to get the `Register` method of `SimpleIoc`. For now, I have no better idea than to "find" it using `.Where`. *Please feel free to improve this statement!*
- Finally, I used `MakeGenericMethod` with the type of the `ViewModelBase` derivate.

---

```
Type[] viewModels = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
    .SelectMany(assembly => assembly.GetTypes())
    .Where(type => typeof(ViewModelBase).IsAssignableFrom(type) && type != typeof(ViewModelBase))
    .ToArray();

MethodInfo registerMethod = typeof(SimpleIoc)
    .GetMethods()
    .Where(method => method.Name == nameof(SimpleIoc.Default.Register) && method.GetParameters().Length == 0 && method.GetGenericArguments().Length == 1)
    .First();

foreach (Type viewModel in viewModels)
{
    registerMethod
        .MakeGenericMethod(viewModel)
        .Invoke(SimpleIoc.Default, new object[0]);
```

---

...And with the properties at the top of the ViewModelLocator class: I don't think it can be done with reflection and misusing XAML for this doesn't seem like good practice to me. But, to make life easier, I created a simple method.

The `singleton` parameter defines whether or not the instance should be single or get a unique key each time. I defined the MainWindow as singleton in my application and the other ViewModels are not singletons in my scenario.

```
public WindowMainViewModel WindowMain => GetInstance<WindowMainViewModel>(true);
public WindowAboutViewModel WindowAbout => GetInstance<WindowAboutViewModel>(false);

private static TService GetInstance<TService>(bool singleton)
{
    return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<TService>(singleton ? null : Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
}
```